# Solve $\tan 2x = 1/\sqrt{3}$ for $-180\leq x \leq 180$.

Tags: trigonometry

Solve $\tan 2x = 1/\sqrt{3}$ for $-180\leq x \leq 180$.

I can't manage to figure out how to solve this question or apply the patterns from it to other questions and would appreciate it if someone could please guide me.

Comment: To obtain $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\csc x$, $\sec x$, and $\cot x$, respectively, type \sin x, \cos x, \tan x, \csc x, \sec x, \cot x when you are in math mode.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$2x=m180^\circ+\arctan\dfrac1{\sqrt3}$$ where $m$ is any integer.

Now $\arctan\dfrac1{\sqrt3}=30^\circ$

Answer (score 0):

Applying $\arctan $ on both sides gives
$$2x=\frac{\pi}{6}+k{\pi}{}$$
$$x=\frac{\pi}{12}+k\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Can you find other solutions in this interval?